# When projective modules become free modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module, free-modules

A common theorem is that every projective modules over a PID are free and we know that every projective modules over commutative local rings are free too. Also every finitely generated projective module over a polynomial ring $K[x_1,\ldots, x_n ]$ over a field $K$ is free (Serre Conjecture) and in 1976 proved by Quillen and Suslin. I want to know for $n=2$ how it works.

Any comments and guidances are very welcome.

Comment: The case $n=1$ reduces to the PID case, so nothing to see there, I think?

Comment: $K[x,y]$ is not a PID. The ideal $\langle x,y\rangle$ is not principal.

Comment: Yes, it is not a PID. So for $n=2$ is not obvious anymore. Is it hard to proof for $n=2$?

Comment: Not trivial. Seshadri proved this in 1958. @Mohan has a very nice article about this: http://www.math.wustl.edu/~kumar/papers/seshadri.pdf

Comment: Thank you so much. It us very useful.

Comment: @user26857 Thank you for your kind comment.